# Flip from one ViewController to another iBooks Style

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigation, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to load in content from a database and allow the user to flip through it like pages, then at the end of the content, give them options to go to another section of content (probably with buttons). The content is currently just formatted with html, but how do I implement the buttons to navigate? I'm a little new to Xcode so maybe I'm not even looking in the right direction.

Comment: UIPageViewController is exactly what you need. I can see that you tagged your questions with it, so you obviously know about the class. What exactly about it do you not understand?

Comment: specifically, trying to figure out how to instantiate a new view with it I think is where I'm failing. I'm trying to be able to flip back and forth between two views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer a this opensource: https://github.com/devindoty/iBooks-Flip-Animation

this is very little code and perfectly works.